# Range Selector - Min & Max Dates with missing days

Tags: highcharts

I´ve some troubles with the range selector and the 1 year range (as example).

When there is no value for today() - 1 year, Highstocks seems to automatically choose the next "newer" value. (e.g. today() - 1 year + 1 day).

But we need to choose the value before.

Example:

Highstocks - Behavior:  (1Y from 2012-02-26)
  Mo (2012-02-27) - Mo (2013-02-26)

Behavior - Needed:
  Fr (2012-02-24) - Mo (2013-02-26)

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setExtremes() to define your own range.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()

Comment: Hmm, I want to use the integrated Range Selector (1y, 2y, 5y) and the Date Input Boxes. Is there any way to modify their "setExtremes" Behavior?

Comment: In buttons you can define how many units of the defined type shoudl be used. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.buttons